# JSTL expression evaluation from a string

Tags: string, jsp, el

Is it possible to evaluate a String as EL expression in JSP and get value from it?

I need an expression like  `${model.${fieldPath}}` where fieldPath will contain the required object path from a nested object model.

I can get the actual field path by using  but I am not sure how to evaluate a string and get the value from it

Any help regarding this would be highly appreciated.

Comment: This is not JSTL. This is EL (Expression Language). JSTL a taglib as shown here: http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/ I've removed the JSTL tag.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure I understood it correctly, but I think you just need this expression:

```
${model[fieldPath]}
```

In EL dot operator and `[]` subscription are basically the same: different syntax, but the same access.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But in our case "fieldPath" value was pointing to a complex structure like "matrixAssumptions[assumptionId].data[rowName].data[matrixColumns[0]].percentage".
When I try to use [] instead of EL dot, it is not able to find such field in the object and throws exception.

Comment: @Venkatesh: What exception specifically?  You should be able to put the whole expression into the brackets in `${model[...]}` if it gives a valid property name (valid for `${model}`, that is).

Comment: I am also looking for an answer here.  if fieldPath = "mycollection[5]", ${model['mycollection[5]']} doesnt work, due to the nested square brackets, but ${model.mycollection[5]} does work.

Comment: The error is: 


javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: The class 'path.to.myModelBean' does not have the property 'mycollection[5]'.

Comment: @thetoolman: What you want is not directly possible with EL as far as I know.  You need to write some function for it (or maybe there's something ready in JSTL, but I don't know as I don't use it).  To me it feels like EL is practically useless without custom functions.  BTW, Apache `PropertyBean` provides access to nested properties.

Answer (score 1):

`<c:set var="fieldPath" value="${fieldPath}" />
${model.get(fieldPath)}`